# In neo4j, can we cast a duration into seconds?

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to get the difference between 2 values of type datetime as an integer of seconds? The closer I can get is having a duration type value, which is not very precise because it's based on the dates passed as input.

Here is an example. Both of these queries return `"P1M0DT0S"`

`RETURN duration.between(datetime("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), 
                         datetime("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z"))
RETURN duration.between(datetime("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z"), 
                         datetime("2018-03-01T00:00:00Z"))`

If you look carefully, this is the duration between January 1st and February 1st and then February 1st and March 1st. They both yield "1 month", but one month is 31 days and the other is 28. I need it in seconds.

I tried the obvious, like calling `toInteger` on the result but it doesn't work.

`Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected Float, Integer, Number or String but was Duration (line 1, column 26 (offset: 25))
"RETURN toInteger(duration.between(datetime("2018-03-01T00:00:00Z"), datetime("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z")))"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two answers. One with duration:

`RETURN duration.inSeconds(datetime("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), 
                           datetime("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z")).seconds`

One with datetime:

`RETURN datetime("2018-03-01T00:00:00Z").epochSeconds - datetime("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z").epochSeconds`